# web.config transformations in redgate for visual studio not being applied

Tags: redgate, config-transformation

I have run across an interesting issue that I have not been able to find a solution for. We currently use the redgate deployment manager addon for visual studio to help streamline our deployment process, however, whenever we publish using the deployment manager it does not take the web.dev.config transformation file that we created into account.

At first, I thought that it might be a syntax issue so I found [a tool](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/) that confirmed our syntax was correct. I tried a standard "publish" within visual studio (just going to a file system to make it easy) and the web.config file does change appropriately. It is only with the redgate deployment manager that the file does not change.

I was curious if anybody else had run into this issue with redgate or if they have any idea which way to look as I have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible causes:

- Web.config transforms are applied based on the name of the environment you are deploying to.  For example, if you have an environment called "Development", you need to call your web.config transform web.Development.config.
- Files to be included in the published package need to have build action set to Content.  This applies for web.config transforms, but also any static content, such as html/css.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!

I tried what you are suggesting and both the web.config and web.dev.config files were deployed, however, the transformations were not done so both config files were sitting separately on the server.

I tried a standard publish through visual studio and the transforms still work as expected. Only when I use the redgate deployment manager am I running into the transformation issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'll contact you directly to get log files.